# Remote Job Alerts location criteria are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Job alerts appear to be broken.

There are two alerts:

- Jobs matching “c#” allowing remote work
- Jobs matching “c#” within 20 miles of Corvallis, OR

None of the jobs listed meet the location criteria, only the C# criterion.

Here is my latest job alert:

```
Stack Overflow Careers
The following are new Stack Overflow Careers job listings per your subscription

Jobs matching “c#” allowing remote work Manage

C# Developer at Carle Foundation Hospital
Urbana, IL
asp.net c# 
The Senior C# Developer participates in analysis, program design, coding, QA, documentation,…
Agile Windows Developer at Funambol Inc.
Pavia, Italy
c# windows-phone windows tdd 
We are looking for a Windows Developer to join our Mobile and Desktop Clients team. If you have…
C# / PHP Developer, Exeter at Sound in Theory Ltd
Exeter, UK
£25,000 - £35,000 c# linq sql-server php 
£25k - £35k based on experience and skills Equity deal a possibility for a truly…
Senior C# Software Engineer (Rockstars or Ninjas need not apply) at Fonetic Solutions SL
Madrid, Spain (offers visa sponsorship)
€30,000 - €50,000 c# 
We are after a seasoned and well rounded software engineer that will not only not back down before…
Android Entwickler at Card eMotion
Wien, Österreich
android java unity 
Konzeption und Programmierung innovativer Mobile Augmented Reality Apps. Verantwortlichkeit…
.NET Developer at mBank S.A.
Warsaw, Poland
c# .net asp.net ado.net 
Główne zadania: przygotowywanie oprogramowania oraz realizacja poszczególnych…
Server Software Engineer at Boss Fight Entertainment
Dallas, TX (offers relocation)
Provides Equity c# amazon-web-services linux node.js 
Boss Fight Entertainment is looking for a server engineer to help us build things that thrive under…
Backend C# Developer (Freemium SAAS, 100K+ users ) at ActivTrak
Dallas, TX
asp.net mysql c# saas 
Dallas-based startup www.activtrak.com has an opening for a front-end web developer. We have a…
Principal Software Engineer – Windows C++ and C# at VaultLogix, LLC
Danvers, MA
c# c++ windows 
A cloud software company is looking for a Windows C++ and C# developer for our cloud backup…
Lead Web Developer - C#/.Net at Crate and Barrel
Northbrook, IL
c# asp.net-mvc sql nosql 
Crate and Barrel is one of America’s most exciting housewares specialty retailer with 100+…
Web Developer, Full Stack at Ayuda Media Systems
New York, NY
asp.net-mvc c# javascript html5 
Is it reasonable to expect mere mortals to have mastery over every facet of the development stack?…
Senior Web Developer – C#/.Net at Crate and Barrel
Northbrook, IL
c# asp.net mvc sqlserver 
Crate and Barrel is one of America’s most exciting housewares specialty retailer with 100+…
C# ASP.NET Web Developers working on large-scale, high profile projects at GOSS Interactive Limited
Plymouth, UK (offers relocation)
£30,000 - £45,000 java javascript oop html 
We are looking for experienced C# ASP.NET Web Developers to join our friendly, innovative and…
Software Developer for particle accelerators at High Voltage Engineering
Amersfoort, Netherlands
python c# c twincat 
To further strengthen our software department we are looking for an experienced and energetic…
Senior Software Engineer- developing software for integrating payment systems at PaymentSense
London, UK
£55,000 - £70,000 c# c++ .net windows 
You are:  Excited to work with new technology in the quickly growing payment…
С# Developer (hot software products for virtualiazation) at Veeam Software
Saint Petersburg, Russia
c# .net winapi sql 
Мы предлагаем принять участие в разработке самых горячих программных продуктов на рынке…
Software Engineer at Unchained Labs
Pleasanton, CA
c# wpf mvvm user-interface 
Assist in development of a new data analysis application, with particular responsibility for  …
Software Application Developer at Lorton Data
Minneapolis, MN
c# java asp.net sql-server 
We have an excellent opportunity for a software developer.  This position involves working…
Senior Software Engineer at Gwynn Group, Inc.
Irving, TX (offers relocation)
$100,000 - $150,000 c# asp.net-mvc angularjs entity-framework 
Who you are: A highly-motivated, energetic and experienced full-stack web developer with a passion…
C# ASP.net MVC Developer at Gravity Supply Chain
Southend-on-Sea, UK
£25,000 - £45,000 asp.net-mvc sql-server c# asp.net 
At Gravity we understand the challenge of turning complicated data into easily understandable…

Jobs matching “c#” within 20 miles of Corvallis, OR Manage

C# Developer at Carle Foundation Hospital
Urbana, IL
asp.net c# 
The Senior C# Developer participates in analysis, program design, coding, QA, documentation,…
Agile Windows Developer at Funambol Inc.
Pavia, Italy
c# windows-phone windows tdd 
We are looking for a Windows Developer to join our Mobile and Desktop Clients team. If you have…
C# / PHP Developer, Exeter at Sound in Theory Ltd
Exeter, UK
£25,000 - £35,000 c# linq sql-server php 
£25k - £35k based on experience and skills Equity deal a possibility for a truly…
Senior C# Software Engineer (Rockstars or Ninjas need not apply) at Fonetic Solutions SL
Madrid, Spain (offers visa sponsorship)
€30,000 - €50,000 c# 
We are after a seasoned and well rounded software engineer that will not only not back down before…
Android Entwickler at Card eMotion
Wien, Österreich
android java unity 
Konzeption und Programmierung innovativer Mobile Augmented Reality Apps. Verantwortlichkeit…
.NET Developer at mBank S.A.
Warsaw, Poland
c# .net asp.net ado.net 
Główne zadania: przygotowywanie oprogramowania oraz realizacja poszczególnych…
Server Software Engineer at Boss Fight Entertainment
Dallas, TX (offers relocation)
Provides Equity c# amazon-web-services linux node.js 
Boss Fight Entertainment is looking for a server engineer to help us build things that thrive under…
Backend C# Developer (Freemium SAAS, 100K+ users ) at ActivTrak
Dallas, TX
asp.net mysql c# saas 
Dallas-based startup www.activtrak.com has an opening for a front-end web developer. We have a…
Principal Software Engineer – Windows C++ and C# at VaultLogix, LLC
Danvers, MA
c# c++ windows 
A cloud software company is looking for a Windows C++ and C# developer for our cloud backup…
Lead Web Developer - C#/.Net at Crate and Barrel
Northbrook, IL
c# asp.net-mvc sql nosql 
Crate and Barrel is one of America’s most exciting housewares specialty retailer with 100+…
Web Developer, Full Stack at Ayuda Media Systems
New York, NY
asp.net-mvc c# javascript html5 
Is it reasonable to expect mere mortals to have mastery over every facet of the development stack?…
Senior Web Developer – C#/.Net at Crate and Barrel
Northbrook, IL
c# asp.net mvc sqlserver 
Crate and Barrel is one of America’s most exciting housewares specialty retailer with 100+…
C# ASP.NET Web Developers working on large-scale, high profile projects at GOSS Interactive Limited
Plymouth, UK (offers relocation)
£30,000 - £45,000 java javascript oop html 
We are looking for experienced C# ASP.NET Web Developers to join our friendly, innovative and…
Software Developer for particle accelerators at High Voltage Engineering
Amersfoort, Netherlands
python c# c twincat 
To further strengthen our software department we are looking for an experienced and energetic…
Senior Software Engineer- developing software for integrating payment systems at PaymentSense
London, UK
£55,000 - £70,000 c# c++ .net windows 
You are:  Excited to work with new technology in the quickly growing payment…
С# Developer (hot software products for virtualiazation) at Veeam Software
Saint Petersburg, Russia
c# .net winapi sql 
Мы предлагаем принять участие в разработке самых горячих программных продуктов на рынке…
Software Engineer at Unchained Labs
Pleasanton, CA
c# wpf mvvm user-interface 
Assist in development of a new data analysis application, with particular responsibility for  …
Software Application Developer at Lorton Data
Minneapolis, MN
c# java asp.net sql-server 
We have an excellent opportunity for a software developer.  This position involves working…
Senior Software Engineer at Gwynn Group, Inc.
Irving, TX (offers relocation)
$100,000 - $150,000 c# asp.net-mvc angularjs entity-framework 
Who you are: A highly-motivated, energetic and experienced full-stack web developer with a passion…
C# ASP.net MVC Developer at Gravity Supply Chain
Southend-on-Sea, UK
£25,000 - £45,000 asp.net-mvc sql-server c# asp.net 
At Gravity we understand the challenge of turning complicated data into easily understandable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the report, Kevin. We released a bad version of job search that caused that bad e-mail to be sent to you. We fixed it on Sunday, so things should be OK again. Sorry for the bug and the annoying e-mail.